# Disable SOAP Schema Validation, JAX-WS and JAXB, How?

Tags: validation, jax-ws

Out of the blue several previously working SOAP calls I do from Java code give "DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: unexpected element...".

It is complaining about about the response object.  A few things though; it had been working fine, I did not change the schema or the EJB, or the caller code, I do no have a scheme validation feature on the port, and the response looks just fine to me.  It is the client side that is complaining.  The server successfully executes the request without comment.

I think my Eclipse environment may be malfunction.

Is there a way to disable client side schema validation of the response from the service or port object?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out and it was Eclipse (Helios) as I suspected.  It turns out that if anything is incorrect with the Java EE perspective and/or any enterprise projects, Eclipse will quietly stop rebuilding things.

I found this out when I deleted everything under build/classes, and then nothing would run.  An unrelated project was pointed at a no longer valid server profile.

How this resulted in the behavior I saw is unknown.  And it would still be nice to know how to disable validation.  It is supposed to off by default, but that but is not.